# Concatenate XML From Various XML Columns without type casting to string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, concatenation, for-xml-path

I have three XML columns in my SQL Table (single row table just used for storing XML) and the XML structure is something like this:

In Column 1 -

```
<Column1XML>
    ....
</Column1XML>
```

In Column 2 -

```
<Column2XML>
    ....
</Column2XML>
```

In Column 3 -

```
<Column3XML>
    ....
</Column3XML>
```

The final resultant XML that I am looking for is:

```
<SomeTagName>
    <Column1XML>
        ....
    </Column1XML>
    <Column2XML>
        ....
    </Column2XML>
    <Column3XML>
        ....
    </Column3XML>
</SomeTagName>
```

How can I obtain this required structure without doing string concatenation? I am sure there must be a way out with Typed XML.

Thanks in advance for looking up my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways for you.

Sample data

```
declare @T table
(
  Col1 xml,
  Col2 xml,
  Col3 xml
)

insert into @T values
(
'<Column1XML></Column1XML>',
'<Column2XML></Column2XML>',
'<Column3XML></Column3XML>'
)
```

Use the root name as column alias

```
select Col1 as 'SomeTagName',
       Col2 as 'SomeTagName',
       Col3 as 'SomeTagName' 
from @T
for xml path('')
```

Use `*` as column alias and specify a `path()`.

```
select Col1 as '*',
       Col2 as '*',
       Col3 as '*' 
from @T
for xml path('SomeTagName')
```

Result:

```
<SomeTagName>
  <Column1XML />
  <Column2XML />
  <Column3XML />
</SomeTagName>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work :(. The result is not enclosed in <SomeTagName> as the root. Instead, each of the individual xml come wrapped in <SomeTagName>. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did exactly as you mentioned - created a temp table with xml columns - SELECT [Col1XML] AS '*',
       [Col2XML] AS '*'
FROM @TempTable
FOR XML PATH ('SomeTagName')

Comment: Do you have your XML as different columns on the same row or as the same column but multiple rows?

Comment: Resultant XML: <SomeTagName><Column1XML>...</Column1XML></SomeTagName><SomeTagName><Column2XML>...</Column2XML></SomeTagName>

Comment: I have XML in the same row but multiple columns. [This is a single row table, with three columns]. Each cell has one XML. I need to combine these three XML into one wrapped in a single root node. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need the table variable for this to work. It is just there to provide you with something that you can test the solution on. Replace it with you tables name.

Comment: You can test the solution [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75509) and see that it works. It has to be something else in your case. To make the nodename specified in `path` do appear more than once you got to have more than one row in the resultset.

Comment: Thanks @Mikael. I tried your example as-is in SQL server, and it works. I have a very complicated structure for the 3 XMLs. Don't know why it is behaving differently for that. OR may be I must be making a small mistake somewhere. That for pointing out the nice online tool to run query.